# URL rewriting and internal links on Apache

Tags: apache-httpd, rewrite, weblogic

I have a 2.2 Apache with the weblogic plugin enabled, which it simply redirects all the requests to the application server. Basically, when I call the page http://myip/blabla/home.page, it is a page resident on the application server.
What I need to do is to understand how to perform a couple of things:

1. When I ask for http://myip/home.page the Apache should give me the http://myip/blabla/home.page.
2. The internal links of the home.page should be with the "blabla" removed.
3. When I click on the modified link, the page served should be the http://myip/blabla/linked.page but with the URL rewritten like this: http://myip/linked.page

Comment: Which attempts on URL rewriting you made?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I finally got it working!
First, you must redirect http://myip/home.page to http://myip/blabla/home.page.
And then, hide the folder.
So:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
Redirect "/home.page" "/blabla/home.page"
RewriteRule ^$ blabla/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blabla/$1
```

the code above place to your apache config etc. or .htaccess file.

Test it on http://rewrite_test.miegl.cz/, when you call [index.php](http://rewrite_test.miegl.cz/)
it will redirect you to [test/index.php](http://rewrite_test.miegl.cz/test/index.php) and it will hide the folder. But still you can call other pages like [hello.php](http://rewrite_test.miegl.cz/hello.php) from root without problem.